# ¿Como hacer aparecer info o documentación de ayuda en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: plugin, vscode, extensiones, documentacion, jsdoc

Por ejemplo en los IDE *Eclipse* y *Netbeans* se pueden configurar para que mediante una tecla o situándote encima de alguna palabra reservada te aparezca **una ventana con ayuda explicando como funciona** tal palabra reservada etc.. si es en Java te muestra el *Javadoc* y así..

Quiero saber si esto también es posible en **Visual Studio Code** ya que cuando uno esta aprendiendo es genial poder tener esta ventana que te explique como funciona tal "comando o Función", ya sea en Java, JavaScript, C++, etc..

Estuve buscando entre las extenciones pero no consegui, busque con palabras como javadoc, doc, documentation, helper, info, etc..

Lo que he visto hasta ahora que es lo mas cerca es presionar la tecla *Ctrl* y posar el *cursor del ratón* en la palabra que se quiere conocer para mostrar la información sencilla de como funciona y si tiene documentación agregada esta aparece también. Ahora hay algún plugin que agregue mas descripciones? o que trabaje con Internet para buscar el significado y función en linea? 
Porque lo que quiero es poder estudiar la función sin tener que cambiar de navegador o pantalla, que ahí mismo rápido y seguro se consiga la información necesaria de dicha función

Comment: Sirve esto? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition

Comment: No estoy seguro si es exactamente lo que buscas pero existen diferentes extensiones https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense "intellisense" para diferentes tipos de lenguajes

Comment: Mmm gracias, no es exactamente lo que busco, no parece dar mas información de lo que ya da VSC por defecto.. usando esta plugin como puedes acceder a dicha información? que tanto te describe?

Answer (score 0):

Dándole a click derecho en la línea en `peek` y dentro en `peek definition` puedes ver el código (al menos el tipo de los parámetros de entrada), pero no sé si hay alguna ventana con la documentación simple y clara.

Comment: Si conozco ese metodo con el Alt+F12, pero igualmente muchas no posee descripción  de su uso.. Ejm: Estando en JS si tengo la funcion .getElementById() y uso el metodo de ctrl o el alt+f12 me muestra la doc.. pero si lo hago con .setInterval()o getContext().. entonces nada.. entiendes?

Answer (score 0):

en python podemos usar, help(), ejemplo help(print) tambien podemos iterar entre sus atributos o metodos dir(Init)

Answer (score 0):

se puede hacer al menos para java pero debes instalar el extensión pack jack:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack

Despues de eso, puedes poner el cursor sobre la linea y te da el javadoc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de otros lenguajes no sabría, pero supongo que puedes instalarte la extensión de dicho lenguaje, lo puedes checar en la doc de vscode en la sección de lenguaje

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview